# Devise: path helper for a resource within two scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to achieve the following:

I have two entry points to the application (/admin and /sales)
I have generated a resource (rails generate scaffold) which is called `customers`. Admin and sales users will need to access this resource from both routes. eg. /admin/customers and /sales/customers.

**This is working so far, here comes the actual problem**. Although I'm logged in as a `sales` user, the path helpers (for example **`new_customer_path`**) all point to `/admin/*`

My routes.rb file:

```
authenticated :user, ->(u) { u.role == 'admin' } do
  scope '/admin' do
    resources :customers
    root 'default#index', as: :admin_authenticated_root
  end
end

authenticated :user, ->(u) { u.role.start_with? 'sales' } do
  scope '/sales' do
    resources :customers
    root 'default#index', as: :sales_authenticated_root
  end
end
```

With this I end up with the following routes.

```
customers      GET    /admin/customers(.:format)          customers#index
               POST   /admin/customers(.:format)          customers#create
new_customer   GET    /admin/customers/new(.:format)      customers#new
edit_customer  GET    /admin/customers/:id/edit(.:format) customers#edit
customer       GET    /admin/customers/:id(.:format)      customers#show
               PATCH  /admin/customers/:id(.:format)      customers#update
               PUT    /admin/customers/:id(.:format)      customers#update
               DELETE /admin/customers/:id(.:format)      customers#destroy

               GET    /sales/customers(.:format)          customers#index
               POST   /sales/customers(.:format)          customers#create
               GET    /sales/customers/new(.:format)      customers#new
               GET    /sales/customers/:id/edit(.:format) customers#edit
               GET    /sales/customers/:id(.:format)      customers#show
               PATCH  /sales/customers/:id(.:format)      customers#update
               PUT    /sales/customers/:id(.:format)      customers#update
               DELETE /sales/customers/:id(.:format)      customers#destroy
```

I really need to find a proper solution, since updating all the code generated by the scaffold generator doesn't seem feasible to me.

There must be a better way than different path helpers for each scope. I don't want to do something like this (in every generated file):

```
`send("#{current_user.role}_customers_path")`
```

I was under the impression, that the admin routes would not even be loaded when I'm logged in as a sales user, but I just started out with working with devise, so I have only very little knowledge about it.

**Edit:**

I guess I could just create a helper and override the path helpers rails is providing:

```
def customers_path
  if current_user.role == 'sales'
    sales_customers_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  scope '/admin', as: :admin do
    resources :customers
    root 'default#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end
```

and the same for `/sales` scope.

**UPDATE**: Oh, I see it now, you actually don't want 2 different paths, but instead generic helper that would give different values depending on `current_user` value. Sorry, routes don't work this way, they get loaded (all of them!) at the application boot time (that's why you can't "delete" some routes depending on your constraint during the request) and first matched one from top to bottom is taken.

Yes, your solution in `EDIT` section is one way to go, but I'd rather used my custom helper for that, because otherwise it would be great surprise for newcomer in your project why the same url_helper produces different urls, until he finally stumbles to your overriden helper.

Comment: while this generates prefixed path helpers `sales_customers_path`, just this is not going to solve the problem. Now I have two sets of route helpers and none of them match the helper that is used when generating a resource via the scaffolding generator.

When I overwrite the path helper along the lines of the method I added under "Edit:", then that's going to work. But why is this necessary? Shouldn't it be possible to have the exact same path helper in each "authenticated" namespace?

Comment: thank you very much for your update. so what you are suggesting is not overriding the path helper, but instead creating my own helper (methods), that handle the "selection" of the correct path based on the user role. that means every file that is generated will have to be edited. I take it that is the cleanest solution. Bummer.

Comment: That will add clarity to your system, which is (in my opinion of course) is the most important thing in programming. Yes, you'll have to change a lot of files, and now you know that scaffolding is evil :)

Comment: It looks like. ;) So in general: would you advise to not use scaffolding at all?

Comment: As all tools it can be handy when used knowledgeably. Scaffolding is very useful, especially at the start of the project, but you need to keep an eye on generated files, so if you notice a lot of duplication, you need to aggressively refactor it. Personally, I rarely use resource scaffolding in the middle of the project (it generates too much files), usually only for migrations and controllers, everything else I create manually.

Comment: Thank you very much for elaborating on this.